# The engine "node" is incompatible with this module. Expected version "x". Got "x"

Tags: node.js, amazon-web-services, sass

I am trying to deploy to aws and get

```
The engine "node" is incompatible with this module. Expected version "16.17.0". Got "10.24.0
```

I've tried upgrading the node, also in the package.json

and running

```
$ yarn install --ignore-engines
```

In project If I check node version

```
node -v
```

I get

```
v16.17.0
```

Package.json

```
  "engines":{
"node":"16.17.0"
```

},

But still the same error. I am fairly new to this so appreciate any help you might able to offer!

Comment: Hello. Did you also installed the new node version or just bumped it on package.json? That error says you are running a 10.24.0 node version, and you will not install an upgraded one using yarn. If you can't upgrade node, then you should consider downgrading sass.

Comment: i've upgraded Node using brew & nvm and then nvm use, while also updating the info in package.json but still getting the same message. I am relatively new to this so I hope I am now missing anything critical here

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Turns out this was a DOCKER issue.

I updated node for my project but not for my containers, I had to rebuild my containers with the correct node.